# Derivative in the sense of distribution of an integral w.r.t. a measure

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, distribution-theory

I want to take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ of the following function in the sense of distribution: $C(t,x)=\int(y-x)_+ d\mu_t(y)$.
The goal is to recover the distribution function of $\mu_t$, namely $\mu_t((-\infty,x])=...$. Can someone help me in this point? I am not so familiar with derivatives in the sense of distributions...

Comment: Is the variable $t$ relevant here?

Comment: no, not really. I just adopt the notation given in the article